# How to synchronize sound playback in android?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm writing my first android app, trying to playback two 10min soundfiles synchronously (imagine an instrumental track and an acapella), to be able to change the volume of each track independently). I am using two MediaPlayers for this, since a SoundPool is targeted at shorter audio samples as far as I read.

Now my problem is that, when pausing and resuming the playback, sometimes the players are not synchronous anymore, even though I set their positions to the same value before resuming playback.

I know that this is kind of inevitable, because they cannot be started at exactly the same moment and they may require different amounts of time for starting playback, but: Is there maybe any other approach to meet my requirements?

Comment: Are you testing this on the emulator or an actual device?

Comment: I am testing on the emulator at the moment.

Comment: maybe you can write a thread which can monitor the sync status of both of the players, and make corrections to position to one of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at [JetPlayer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/jetplayer.html), this may accomplish what you want as far as synchronization.

To use it you create audio channels (your instrument channel and vocal channel) as MIDI files in a track and the player can keep them synchronized while allowing you to mute or unmute the different channels as appropriate.

The user guide for creating JET resouces can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/jet/jetcreator_manual.html).

Comment: Thank you, this sounds promising.